# Error when run gulp start

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm searching and searching and I can´t find the error.
Now I hope someone help me.

npm -v

[18:54:13] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[18:54:13] CLI version 3.9.0
[18:54:13] Local version 3.9.0

gulp -v

5.6.0

```
$ gulp start
[18:47:59] Requiring external module babel-core/register
/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:558
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /config/index.js: Unexpected token (31:17)
  29 | const bothConfig = require('./both');
  30 | 
> 31 | export default { ...bothConfig, ...envConfig };
     |                  ^
  32 | 
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdentifier (/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4332:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parsePropertyName (/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4156:96)
    at Parser.parsePropertyName (/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:6229:23)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseObj (/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4045:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3719:19)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:7238:22)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3474:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

`export default{bothConfig, envConfig};`